Duplicates in Android Jetpack Compose with Custom Ripple Effect
Here's an anomaly: when I add a LocalRippleConfiguration to my theme, a duplicate appears in the Dialog with a transparent background.
CompositionLocalProvider(
    value = LocalRippleConfiguration provides RippleConfiguration(
        rippleAlpha = RippleAlpha(
            pressedAlpha = 0.5f,
            focusedAlpha = 0.4f,
            draggedAlpha = 0.4f,
            hoveredAlpha = 0.4f
        ),
        color = LACE
    )
) {
    MaterialTheme(content = content)
}

[https://i.sstatic.net/l8HTQx9F.png]
With  .background(Color.Whatever) the double is not visible, but I need Transparent. Without LocalRippleConfiguration  there is no duplicate, but ripple effect is practically invisible.
I tried changing and deleting variables inside RippleAlpha

Rather than define your ripple outside MaterialTheme(), try defining it inside MaterialTheme() and see if that makes a difference.
